# edit an image in place

Tags: image, powershell

So I've got a small script which opens an image:

```
    $file = ([System.IO.FileInfo]$FilePath);
    if ($file.Exists) {
        $imgInMemory = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($file.FullName);
        [...irrelevant code to the question...]
        $imgInMemory.Save($($file.FullName + '.tmp'), $codecInfo, $encoderParams);
        Move-Item -Path $($file.FullName + '.tmp') -Destination $file.FullName -Force;
    }
```

So, I load the file contents with the Image.FromFile method, and I'm trying to save it back to the same filename. I have tried:

1. $imgInMemory.Dispose() and $graphics.Dispose() followed by the .tmp save call and the move-item call seen above. This still gives an access denied exception.

What am I missing in terms of an open file handle because it would appear that even a -Force on the move-item only removes the .tmp file without overwriting the original file. So if you're doing something, like adding pins to an image, is it possible to save the output back to the original file? And if so, how?

Comment: What is `$PinsData` and `$pinScale`, without information on these variables we can't reproduce your code

Comment: Just set $pinScale to an int of 60, and make $pinsData a custom PS Object with the noted properties - it's actually a DB result set.

Comment: You're the one asking for help, this information should be included in your question or a way to reproduce those variables

Comment: Edited the question to eliminate the need for any such details, I just want to overwrite a file after I've loaded it and manipulated it.

Comment: Do you really want to create a temporary file? Because you can just open a `FileStream` with `RW` access and just overwrite the file

Comment: It's an artifact from another script doing similar work. Would you care to post the relevant code as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this process without the need to create a temporary file, it's unclear why your code could be failing though this should work:

1. Open the file to be overwritten with [`ReadWrite` FileAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileaccess?view=net-7.0).
2. Use the [`FromStream` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) on the input file..
3. [`SetFileLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.length?view=net-6.0) to `0` for the input file before saving the new content to it.
4. Use either [`Save(Stream, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-image-save(system-io-stream-system-drawing-imaging-imagecodecinfo-system-drawing-imaging-encoderparameters)) or [`Save(Stream, ImageFormat)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-image-save(system-io-stream-system-drawing-imaging-imageformat)) overloads.
5. Lastly, call [`Dispose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=net-7.0#system-idisposable-dispose) on all variables.

```bash
using namespace System.IO
using namespace System.Drawing
using namespace System.Drawing.Imaging

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$inFile   = [FileInfo] 'path\to\file1.ext'
$refFile  = 'path\to\file2.ext'

if ($file.Exists) {
    $inStream  = $inFile.Open([FileMode]::Open, [FileAccess]::ReadWrite)

    $inImg  = [Image]::FromStream($inStream)
    $refImg = [Image]::FromFile($refFile)

    # irrelevant code here...

    $inStream.SetLength(0)
    $inImg.Save($inStream, $imageCodecInfo, $encoderParams)
    $refImg, $inImg, $inStream | ForEach-Object Dispose
}
```

Comment: This works in isolation, but I have a new question for the complications I identified this morning. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JaazCole hi, you can ask a new question with the details

Comment: you can @ me again if you decide to ask a new one, if i'm available will try to answer it